# Java generics for optional single value or collection

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to define a container for a whole bunch of classes as some parts of the code will make more sense with a collection but other places will make sense with single values.

Ideally I'd like to do this:

```
public class AllModes<T> {
   private T<Car> car;
   private T<Boat> boat;
   private T<Train> train;
   private T<Plane> plane;
   ...40 more of these...
}
```

then I'd like to use the class like:

```
AllModes<List> allModes;
AllModes<Optional> oneOfEachMode;
```

But I get the error I get is "The type T is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments "

The reason I'm defining these in multiple variables and not a single HashSet based on a superclass is I want to have get methods that return the correct types to avoid consumers of this class needing to cast down everywhere as each object has its own distinct fields.

I also considered just storing a single value list or set but I thought it might less error prone to use the correct type I intended (ie. one value)

Comment: You should use T directly rather classes like Car,Boat etc

Comment: @GauravSrivastav If I do that how do I define all the different variables I need for each type?

Comment: why don't you consider the composite pattern? it looks like it's the case (treating a collection and a single instance in the same way)

Comment: even if it was possible, how would you initialise these collections? `new T()` wouldn't work

Comment: How do you expect your clients to work with this type? I mean, is there a scenario where a client will want to use `AllModes<T>` or is it always going to be either `AllModes<Optional>` or `AllModes<List>`? If it's the latter, the top-level abstraction is useless and you can have different classes for each container type, not even part of the same hierarchy (if you don't care about DRY); and there will be no need for generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't achieve what you want using the Java type system.
Since you can't have a generic container type, you'll need to enforce the invariants with dedicated constructors (or subclasses).

But if you do so, the clients of your class will not be able to distinguish between different container types (`Optional` vs `List`), they will need to work with a generic abstraction (like `Stream`, `Iterator`, `Iterable`, whatever suits you).

Here's an example:

```
public class AllModes {
    private final Supplier<Stream<Car>> cars;
    private final Supplier<Stream<Boat>> boats;

    public AllModes(Optional<Car> car, Optional<Boat> boat) {
        // Assuming Java 8, when Optional did not have a stream() method yet
        this.cars = () -> car.map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty());
        this.boats = () -> boat.map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty());
    }

    public AllModes(List<Car> cars, List<Boat> boats) {
        this.cars = cars::stream;
        this.boats = boats::stream;
    }

    public Stream<Car> getCars() {
        return cars.get();
    }

    public Stream<Boat> getBoats() {
        return boats.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve it this way. Use the `instanceof` operator instead. Here is an example:

```
public class AllModes<T> {
    private T object;

    private void check(T object) {
        if(object instanceof Boat){
            System.out.println("Boat");
            // your code for Boat goes here
        } else if (object instanceof Car) {
            System.out.println("Car");
            // your code for Car goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [The Java™ Tutorials - Why Use Generics?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html):

> By using generics, programmers can implement generic algorithms that work on collections of different types, can be customized, and are type safe and easier to read.

You can have multiple types in class and then you can associated them with the fields. But in your case, you have several fields with some type. A class don't have much dependencies on others. You should design you class in a way that there are no much dependencies there.

```
public class AllModes<T,T1,T2,T3> {
       private T car;
       private T1 boat;
       private T2 train;
       private T3 plane;

}
```

Comment: `AllModes<HashSet<Car>, HashSet<Boat>, ...>` might be fine (actually, no), but how are you going to init the `T`, `T1` ... fields?

Comment: AllModes<Car, Boat, Train, Plane> allModels = new AllModes<>(); But I think you need one at a time.  Do you want to put some default values for your fields ?

Comment: how does a `car` get initialised in the non-argument constructor? I would like to see a complete filled instance of this class. not just a version that compiles.

Comment: These are just 4 unrelated types, like in a `Tuple4`. i.e. the following compiles fine: `new AllModels<List<Car>, Optional<Boat>, Train, String>()`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you take a step back and re-consider what exactly you want to achieve with this container. E.g. ask yourself what its domain is or what the client is supposed to do with `Allmodes<T>`...

Another more concrete question that comes to mind is how exactly you intend to popuplate that `Optional<T>` generically? Will it be the first element in the `List<T>` or the last? Or an element which satisfies a specific `Predicate<T>`?

Your design *doesn't seem to be* that well thought out yet.

What you could do which would come close to what you descibed (in case I got that right) is provide an accessor of type `Stream<T>` as you could get both a `List<T>` aswell as an `Optional<T>` from it. Your client would then have to make that decision and also determine how exactly to derive the `Optional<T>` from the `Stream<T>`.

Comment: I'm trying to group a bunch of types so I can pass the group around, with type safety and for different use cases (lists in some places, single values in others). For example one part of the code would need to be able to pull down all the cars, however another part just wants to have one of each mode (eg. populated off a request based form). I'm aiming to reduce duplication (ie. if a new mode was added it doesn't need to be added to both a list and single version of the grouping class)

Comment: @TownCube sounds to me like the smallest common denominator between `List` and `Optional` or not? Maybe just use a list with one element. An `Option` type can be converted into a `List` with at most one element and back. The [vavr](http://vavr.io) library supports this. It's actually [Value](https://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.0/io/vavr/Value.html#toOption--) which supports it.